# Switch image source between two images

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I want to toggle between two images within a list and update their source depending on some condition. But when the second image is updating, I want the first one to keep the last shown image. Basically what is happending here is that both get updated because source is bound to both. How to make it right in an efficient way?

*Update: I render a D3DImage and want to overlay two images (like chart axes(backImage) and points(targetImage)). Depending on a condition I change the axes or the points image.*

Basically what I have is:

```
List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
imageList.Add(backImage);
imageList.Add(targetImage);

if(condition)
   imageList[0].Source = someSource;
else
   imageList[1].Source = someSource;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're asking... you can't update an `Image.Source` property and still have that `Image` display the old image. However, you can easily do this using XAML and `Binding` to the `Image.Source` property of each `Image`:

Add two properties in your view model or code behind that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
// Don't copy this - implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface properly
public ImageSource ImageSource1 { get; set; } 
public ImageSource ImageSource2 { get; set; }
```

Set these properties:

```
ImageSource1 = ImageSource2 = someSource;
```

Now `Bind` these properties to the `Image` controls:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource1}" />
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource12}" />
```

Now you can set them to the same image or to different images independently:

```
ImageSource2 = anotherSource;
```

Comment: I will try this. I know it is not part of the question but does this lowers performance? Using this method would introduce the possiblity to freeze the image also. Would that lead to any performance improvement over directly changing the image source like I did within my question's code?

Comment: In both of our examples, we are changing the same `Image.Source` in the same way... there's no difference in performance. It is not that the `Image` will be frozen... there are two `Image` controls, so one can be changed without affecting the other. The fact that they can both be set to display the same `Image.Source` is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a BitmapImage to your resources as shown below:

```
   <BitmapImage x:Key="Connected" UriSource="sample.png" />
```

And change your existing code to refer to image :

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
      <Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static my:Object.Instance}, Path=Connected, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Source"
                Value="{StaticResource Connected}"/>
      </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Comment: -1 This is not an answer. If you want to comment on the question, please add a comment using the `add comment` link in the question.

Comment: I get an image source from a D3Dimage. I have two overlaying images. I want update them depending on some condition. It is far more complicated to create two image sources than just switch the target. I hope this makes things clear?

Comment: why don't you use data triggers in xaml directly ?? based on condition/property true or false, you can change the image source rather changing in code.

Comment: If you think that it is a good solution, please give me an example. But keep in mind, I render in a different thread and the condition is also not living in the UI thread. Isn't there a easy solution to do this in code?

Comment: @Shaktisaxena, if you edit your answer to actually present an answer, I will be happy to remove my down vote.

Comment: @Sheridan, changed. I am new here. however, open to learn :) (y)

Comment: +1 for sticking to the rules... as a new user, I would recommend that you take a look at the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) here to see how things are supposed to be done.